# Using Ruby and watir-webdriver, how does one get the XPath of an element if the text is known?

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, watir-webdriver

Using watir-webdriver, I am trying to click the "down" button next to some known text on the screen (in this case, `"An Example"`). When I click the down button, the text itself will move down a list of arbitrary length. I don't always know where the text will appear in the list, and also there is no ID on the text or the down button to uniquely identify the location to click. The button has a class attached (`"rowDown down"`), but as there can be multiple rows of text, the button class is not unique.

In situations where I can't get get a unique ID, I always turn to XPath.

In this case, I know the XPath of the text I care about will end with `/div[2]`
and the button I want to click is in `div[1]`, more specifically the button I want will have XPath ending in `div[1]/button[2]`

The question is, how do I get the XPath for the text using watir-webdriver?
(An example of the full XPath I could be dealing with is `"//*[@id='sortOrder0']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]"`.)
Alternately, and equally acceptable, is there some other, reliable way of getting to the button I care about?

Here is the relevant portion of my HTML, which produces an up arrow and a down arrow next to the words "An Example":

```
<div>
  <button class="rowUp up"></button>
  <br />
  <button class="rowDown down"></button>
</div>
<div>
  An Example
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the text of node during an XPath using `text()`. Therefore you could write an XPath that finds the div with text "An Example", goes to the preceding div and then clicks the down button:

```
browser.button(xpath: '//div[normalize-space(text())="An Example"]
                        /preceding-sibling::div[1]
                        /button[contains(@class, "rowDown")]').click
```

Personally I find this hard to read and error prone. I prefer to use basic locators and leave the XPath generation to Watir-Webdriver's internals. A similar effect to the XPath can be achieved with:

```
browser.div(text: 'An Example').parent.button(class: 'rowDown').click
```

Comment: Thanks, Justin. I'll work with this a little to see if I can get it to do what I need it to do. In your preferred syntax, the button isn't directly inside the parent element but rather there is a div and then a button. My other concern is going straight off the text 'An Example' as the web page in question sometimes has hidden elements. Using the text works the vast majority of the time, but every once in a while watir gets confused.

Comment: With the Watir approach it is fine that the button is within a div. Watir will look for the button anywhere within the parent. I am not sure I understand the concern about using text as it would be no different than using the xpath. However perhaps using a regex will solve it?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know I could just do parent.button. Good to know!

Comment: The concern about using text is that it is possibly not as specific as XPath. That is, the XPath to an element is unique, but if the text appears in multiple places in the HTML (hidden elements or otherwise), just going off the text Watir might try to use an occurrence of the text other than the one we wanted it to find. This concern might be unfounded on the page in question. I'm not sure.

Comment: Just like the xpath, you could scope the searching for the text to a specific element -such as only looking in the sortOrder0 element.

Comment: Finally got it to work, and I used your cleaner implementation. I struggled with it for a bit but eventually realized that "An Example" is in the HTML 3 times but is only visible once. (Not sure why it took me an hour to come around to that issue when only last night I expressed that I knew it could be a problem!) My code in the end was browser.table(id: 'sortOrder0').div(text: 'An Example').parent.button(class: 'rowDown').click . Thanks again, Justin!

Comment: @JustinKo **"Personally I find this hard to read and error prone"** I heard similar words from one of our senior QA too. But I never got chance to ask him why he is saying so. So, "hard to read" I get, but **how it is "error prone"?** Is it only error prone when using "WATIR+Cuke" or in "JAVA Automation" projects also?

Comment: @paul, complicated XPaths are error prone (ie easy to make mistakes) in whatever tool being used. For example, the XPath `button[contains(@class, "rowDown")]` may give unexpected results - eg it will match `<button class="blahrowDownblah">`. In contrast Watir's `browser.button(:class => 'rowDown')` will build the XPath such that the matching is against a full class name. Another common error is starting nested XPaths with `//` instead of `.//` resulting in searching out of the expected scope.